# How to migrate an Resource from an Azure Account to another Azure Account

Tags: azure

I want to migrate an appservice  from an  Azure account and Azure Active Directory tenant to  Azure account and Azure AD tenant. How can I do that? Current solution as detailed by microsoft at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources; details how to migrate resources between subscription with same tenant id.

Any suggestion on how to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When the resource/subscription exists in a different AD tenant you need to change the tenant of one of the subscriptions (i.e. you can only transfer resources where the subscriptions exist in the same tenant).

Note: You can only do this if you are a Service Administrator and signed in using a Microsoft i.e non organizational account.

The first section of the Microsoft documentation you [referenced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources) explains how to do this.